# memory leak in scnetworkreachabilityref

Tags: ios

Could anybody kindly tell me why I am getting a leak in the following code and
also how to remove the leak

```
SCNetworkReachabilityRef reachability = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(kCFAllocatorDefault, (const struct sockaddr*)&zeroAddress);
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`CFRelease(reachability);` after you've finished with `reachability`.